# Thematic mapping

Tags: openlayers-2, thematic-map, geoext-2, ext-js-4

What is the best way to develop thematic maps? I would like to generate pie charts and fill polygons with different colors depending on a parameter value.
I'm working with ExtJS 4.2 and OpenLayers.